# Structuring Memory Viewer Contol in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml

What is the best way to design a memory viewer control (a la Visual Studio's Memory Window)?

The control will be mapped onto a byte array and a value representing the starting address (optionally, the control could be mapped onto an object that interfaces to "memory" directly with read/write methods and events for memory changed).

The display should be something like:

```
start..end
addr: 42 79 74 65 | B y t e
addr: 57 6f 72 64 | W o r d
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [plinth.org](http://www.plinth.org/_images/memorywindow.jpg))</sub>

I'm trying to puzzle out the best way get a sane visual hierarchy such that when you stretch the containing window, it will auto-adjust the contents and you can select the text in either the hex or the ASCII areas and the selection would be reflected in both.

Bonus points if I can make recently changed values a different color.

Am I looking at a stack panel and two rich text boxes where the changing width of the hex box drives the contents of the other two?

Comment: Your description is difficult to follow. Can you construct a rough image of what you want it to look like in paint?

Comment: For an example, fire up VisualStudio, start a project in Debug, Debug->Windows->Memory->Memory1.